# Memory Access Error Inserting Point Into nD Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: windows, cgal, triangulation, delaunay

I'm attempting to implement [Schlomer's Max Min Dist sets](https://kops.uni-konstanz.de/bitstream/handle/123456789/17724/Deussen%20etal.pdf?sequence=1) in N dimensions for a project I'm working on using CGAL's nD Delaunay Triangulation for the algorithm. I'm able to compile and run the example code, but when incorporating the triangulation into my set's class, I get memory access errors after inserting a few points. As far as I can tell, besides the fact that the triangulation is living in the class instance memory space and not main, I'm not diverging significantly from the example code. I am using Dynamic_Dimension_tag instead of a compile-time fixed triangulation, but I tweak the example code to do the same and it's fine. I'll sample the header and source below, detailing the method I'm using to do the point additions. Another set of more experienced eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Header:

```
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <CGAL\Epick_d.h>
#include <CGAL\Delaunay_triangulation.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::container;

typedef CGAL::Triangulation<CGAL::Epick_d<CGAL::Dynamic_dimension_tag>> T;

class DllExport MaxMinDist
{
public:
    MaxMinDist(int);
    const vector<T::Point>& points() const;
    int createPointsFromData(const vector<double>&);
    int dimension(void) const;
    int size(void) const;
private:
    T dt_;
    vector<T::Point> points_;
    double localMinDist(const T::Point&);
    double globalMinDist(void);
    double averageMinDist(void);
    void iterateGlobalFPO(void);
    void iterateLocalFPO(void);
    double toroidalDistanceOnAxis(double, double);
    double toroidalSquaredDistance(const T::Point&, const T::Point&);
};
```

Source:

```
int MaxMinDist::createPointsFromData(const vector<double>& data)
{
    // data supplied doesn't match the dimension
    if (data.size() % dimension() != 0) return -1;
    // break up the data into points
    points_.reserve(data.size() % dimension());
    for (auto iter = data.begin(); iter != data.end(); iter += dimension()) {
        T::Point p(iter, iter + dimension());
        points_.push_back(p);
    }
    // add the points to the triangulation
    T::Vertex_handle hint;
    int i = 0;
    for (auto pt_iter = points_.begin(); pt_iter != points_.end(); ++pt_iter) {
        std::cout << "Processing: " << *pt_iter << ", " << ++i << " of " << int(points_.size()) << std::endl;
        if (T::Vertex_handle() != hint) {
            hint = dt_.insert(*pt_iter, hint);
        }
        else {
            hint = dt_.insert(*pt_iter);
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

The function that is throwing the exception is NT_Convertor, defined in NT_Convertor.h in the CGAL namespace.

NT_Convertor

```
template < class NT1, class NT2 >
struct NT_converter
  : public CGAL::unary_function< NT1, NT2 >
{
    NT2
    operator()(const NT1 &a) const
    {
        return NT2(a);  <-- source of exception
    }
};
```

Ok, further development.

Examining the stack frames, I noted that the library holding the excepting function is "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\bin\libgmp-10.dll". The main project is a plugin for Autodesk Maya. Unfortunately, that self-same library is part of the CGAL install. CGAL has its own copy of the DLL in the linking folder. I removed the MaxMinDistSet class from the project to a new separate project, just a library for itself notably without the includes or linking from OpenMaya. Testing that separate project was successful. I was able to add all points in the test fixture to the Triangulation. So the issue appears to be a conflict between CGAL's libgmp-10.dll and Maya's libgmp-10.dll.

The next question then becomes, can CGAL be build to statically embed its version of the library, or is there a more correct way to resolve the conflict?

Comment: In what dimension did you try, and with how many points?

Comment: In my Test case, I'm using dimension 3, with about six points (three coordinates a piece) to start. The exception gets raised on the on the fourth point. The example uses dimension 7 (spec'd in the type, not dynamic), and pushes 8 (7 coordinates a piece). In my experiments, I changed the example to dynamic, and added a couple more points but couldn't make the error occur even with the modified example code. In the end, I'll need an arbitrary number of coordinates, as the sets will need to be generated for a collection of weighted transforms, using their weights as dimensions of the space.